# How to Navigate from .Net Maui Page to Blazor page on Blazor Hybrid project

Tags: navigation, .net-maui, blazor-hybrid

How to Navigate from .Net Maui Page to Blazor page on Blazor Hybrid project?

Answer (score 2):

You can use code snippet below to `navigate` from .Net Maui Page to Blazor page on Blazor Hybrid project. Notice that I use a button event to trigger it.

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="NavigatetoMain"></button>

@code{

    private void NavigatetoMain(){
       App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend , big love